# ngModel with value inside ngFor but value is blind

Tags: angular

i want update value through input but value is blind

and i search how to solve it but i didn't get answer

html:

```
    <tbody class="text-center" *ngFor="let s of current_other ;">
              <tr *ngIf="s.userId ==userId">

                <td style=" height: 10px; padding: 0%;"> 
                  <input style=" width: 100%; height: 100%;" type="text"
              [(ngModel)]="title_skill_other_update "  value="{{s.title_skill}}" id="title_skill_other_update" name="title_skill_other_update" > 
            
            </td>

                <td style=" height: 10px; padding: 0%;"> 
                  <input style=" width: 100%; height: 100%;" type="text" 
              [(ngModel)]="number_skill_other_update" value="{{s.number_skill}}" id="number_skill_other_update" name="number_skill_other_update"> 
            </td>
              
                <td><button class="btn btn-warning  mr-1" (click)="update_other()" type="button"> edit</button> </td>

              </tr>
            </tbody>
```

TS :

```
title_skill_other_update=""
number_skill_other_update=""

update_other(){
  const data={
    title_skill:this.title_skill_personal_update,
number_skill:this.number_skill_personal_update,
  }
}
```

help if you can or advice me maybe syntax or code is wrong

Comment: func for update value through input

Comment: omg i wrote binding it's = blind 

i'm sorry i edit it

Comment: you might want to use a simple form https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Answer (score -1):

i solved

i just remove title_skill_other_update && number_skill_other_update

and put it value on ngModel and then add on parameters => update_other(data1,data2)

HTML:

```
<tbody class="text-center" *ngFor="let s of current_other ;">
          <tr *ngIf="s.userId ==userId">

            <td style=" height: 10px; padding: 0%;"> 
              <input style=" width: 100%; height: 100%;" type="text"
          [(ngModel)]="s.title_skill"   id="title_skill_other_update" name="title_skill_other_update" > 
        
        </td>

            <td style=" height: 10px; padding: 0%;"> 
              <input style=" width: 100%; height: 100%;" type="text" 
          [(ngModel)]="s.number_skill"  id="number_skill_other_update" name="number_skill_other_update"> 
        </td>
          
            <td><button class="btn btn-warning  mr-1" (click)="update_other(s.title_skill,s.number_skill)" type="button"> edit</button> </td>

          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

TS:

```
update_other(data1,data2){
  const data={
    title_skill:data1,
number_skill:data2,
  }
}
```